# pattern match and add line at the end or start of a line in a text file using sed

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, pattern-matching

I have a text file which contains:

```
First link https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0151/0741/products/2c60070615ceaa44c934ca876fe4ccc0_f304e840-bb1d-4bcf-a993-d966c0b99ae3.jpeg?v=1452842355 
Second link https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0151/0741/products/549542c704da78a0e5208b9f8c2cd26e.jpeg?v=1452842263
Third link https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0151/0741/products/2c60070615ceaa44c934ca876fe4ccc0_70e7e6b9-bedd-40a7-b322-542facf94c05.jpeg?v=1452842230
Fourth link https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0151/0741/products/2c60070615ceaa44c934ca876fe4ccc0_5485fd04-c852-4fd7-b142-92595329568a.jpeg?v=1452841841
lst link https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0151/0741/products/2c60070615ceaa44c934ca876fe4ccc0_fb613b45-fbbb-4b6d-b9c0-45d7f069879e.jpeg?v=1452841831
```

I want to match last url and append a word at start or end of the line using sed.

But it is not working. HELP

output of the command gives this error.

```
$sed -e 's_https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0151/0741/products/2c60070615ceaa44c934ca876fe4ccc0_f304e840-bb1d-4bcf-a993-d966c0b99ae3.jpeg\?v=1452842355 .*_& NOTFOUND_'
sed: -e expression #1, char 148: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: i want to append a word at the end or start of the matched line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `sed` is the not the best tool for this task. There is no way you can pass a plain non-regex string in a sed pattern without doing all the escaping before hand.

Better to use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'index($0, "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0151/0741/products/2c60070615ceaa44c934ca876fe4ccc0_fb613b45-fbbb-4b6d-b9c0-45d7f069879e.jpeg?v=1452841831"){
 $0 = $0 " NOTFOUND"} 1' file
```

`index` function just searched for presence of given URL in a record and if found appends `" NOTFOUND` string at the end.

Equivalent working sed would be this:

```
sed 's~https://cdn\.shopify\.com/s/files/1/0151/0741/products/2c60070615ceaa44c934ca876fe4ccc0_fb613b45-fbbb-4b6d-b9c0-45d7f069879e\.jpeg?v=1452841831.*~& NOTFOUND~' file
```

As you can see it requires you to escape all the DOTs and pick a regex delimiter which is not already present in input string.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `_` as your regex delimiter, when that char shows up in the URLs?

```
[..snip..]/products/2c60070615ceaa44c934ca876fe4ccc0_fb613b45-fb
                                                    ^---
```

You're effectively doing

```
s/.../f
```

and `f` is an unknown modifier for an `s/` regex.

Comment: use a delimiter that ISN'T in the string, or escape the `_` in your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern has an underscore `...fe4ccc0_f304...` which you used as the delimiter for the substitute command. use some other delimiter that does not appear unescaped in the pattern or replacement string.

Try using `|` character instead, as in `s|http://... .*$|& NOT_FOUND|`.

Comment: but it matches all the lines and doesnt even add NOTFOUND word at the end of the line

Comment: I just suggessted you the delimiter. I expect you to write the correct pattern you want to match.

Comment: it matches the pattern but doesnt add the line

Comment: please specify the command executed when you tell about results.